# How do we calculate ratio between three fractions?

Tags: c#

How do we calculate ratio between 3 fractions?

for example

3/2 and 6/4 and 8/3 ?

Comment: You don't. A ratio is by definition between two things.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the ratio between any two fractions can be obtained by cross-multiplying, so

```
a/b : c/d = ad : cb
```

So 3/2 : 6/4 is 24 : 24 (i.e. 1 : 1) and 3/2 : 8/3 is 9:16